# $\int_\gamma\frac{1}{|\xi-z|}\,d|\xi|=2\pi$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

If $z$ is inside $\gamma$, we know $\int_\gamma\frac{1}{|\xi-z|}\,d|\xi|=2\pi$ when $\gamma$ is the circle centered at $z$, I wonder if it's still true if $\gamma$ is an arbitrary closed curve with $z$ inside?

Comment: Not in general. For instance, if $\gamma$ is the unit circle and $z$ is inside $\gamma$, then

$$ \int_{\gamma} \frac{|d\xi|}{|\xi - z|} = \frac{4}{1-|z|}K\left( \frac{2i |z|^{1/2}}{1-|z|} \right), $$

where $K(k)$ is the [*complete elliptic integral of the first kind*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind) and $k$ is the elliptic modulus.

Comment: If you remove both absolute values the result is indeed $2\pi$ if $z$ is inside the (positively oriented, simple) closed curve $\gamma$, and 0 if $z$ is outside.  The integral as written is 0, as Szeto points out.  The version with $|d\xi|$ is $2 \pi$ for $z=0$ when $\gamma$ is a circle, but is generally different from $2 \pi$, as Sangchul Lee says.

Comment: @JimFerry Unfortunately my answer is downvoted :), but anyway...

Comment: @SangchulLee Just a small question: in this case, can we apply the principle of Stokes’ theorem to decompose the integral on a curve into sum of integrals on infinitesimally small circles? Why or why not?

Answer (score 0):

Your integral is wrong.

Since $\gamma$ is a circle about $z$, $|w-z|=R$($R$ is the radius of the circle.

Thus, the integral equals
$$\frac1R\int_\gamma d|w|=\frac1R(|w(2\pi)|-|w(0)|)=0$$

I think you mean 
$$\left\vert\int_\gamma \frac1{w-z}dw\right\vert=2\pi$$
and you wrongly assumed 
$$\left\vert\int_\gamma \frac1{w-z}dw\right\vert=\int_\gamma \frac1{|w-z|}d|w|$$

**Added**:

I might have omitted some details in the original answer.

The parametrization is: $w=z+Re^{i\theta}$.
$$|w|=\sqrt{z^2+R^2+2Rz\cos(\theta)}$$
$$\int_\gamma d|w|=\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{d|w|}{d\theta}d\theta =|w|_{\theta=2\pi}-|w|_{\theta=0}=0 $$

**ADDED 2**:

$d|w|$ does not represent the differential length of curve, but $|dw|$ does.

This is correct:
$$\int_\gamma\frac{1}{|w-z|}|dw|=2\pi$$

Comment: @6666 See my edited answer.